# Removing details

Tags: mesh

I have a model that has amazingly many details that are not really relevant for me. I would instead like to use a normal map for them.

However I have not found a way to remove these details easily. 
The Decimation Modifier did not work well for me, but perhaps I just missed an important setting.

Can anybody tell me how to get rid of these details quickly?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You can try to add a **Shrinkwrap modifier** to the mesh. As you don't need high level of details, you shouldn't catch them with modifier. To adjust level of details, you can add **Subsurf** at 1-st subdivision level. So **Shrinkwrap** will not be able to make details to appear.

Comment: @Mr Zak Nice idea. Maybe you should write an answer?

Comment: @Gonzou maybe, not sure yet. Anyway, I'll be able to add it in several hours, not now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use a ***Dissolve Faces*** option. Select all ***faces*** of the detailed part of your mesh, then press <kbd>X</kbd>*-->**Dissolve Faces***.
[image]

You may also use the **Limited Dissolve** option. Select the faces as above, press <kbd>X</kbd>*-->**Limited Dissolve*** and increase the *Max Angle* factor in a *Tool Shelf* panel . Of course after doing this you'll have to clean up your mesh a bit, but I guess there'll be no problem with that in your case.
[image]

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but I am having an absolutely hard time just selecting the faces, so that is not a good solution for me.

Comment: @tmighty Are you joking? :). You can make this kind of selection in one step. Wait a minute, I'll show you how to do it fast.

Comment: Answer updated. Please see the first .GIF.

Comment: To do **Box Select** press the letter **B** and drag.

Answer (score 1):

It is not extremely clear to me, from the picture, how those vertices are related to the rest of the mesh, however: one quick way could be to select all vertices and X > dissolve vertices to get a n-gon face instead, assigned to their "contour" edges). If you need only quads, then, you can select all the remaining vertex on all edges that you need to remove, one by one and again X > dissolve vertices also them, until you get only the vertices you need to have only quads (you may need to remove remaining a big ngon face and fill the hole with quad faces.

[image]

[image]

[image]